# Android PayPal payment using credit card

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I want to  use the PayPal payment gateway to accept payment through credit card in my android application, but I want to use my own UI for credit card details and make my own payment button.

Is there a way to customize the PayPal UI?

Comment: If you have a script, we can help you with it ;)

Comment: what is your issue??credit card or UI customization??

Comment: UI customization is my problem.